# Facebook API get user accesstoken for app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

I am posting to my facebook wall through my app using my user.
I gave to the app offline access but still, sometimes the accesstoken changes.

I would like to know if its possible to use Facebook API to get the accesstoken?

Right now, I used the example.php from the facebook sdk to login and took the accesstoken from there.

again, I dont want the application accesstoken. I want to user accesstoken of using the app.

Thanks.

Comment: Are 100% sure there is such a thing as user access token?

Comment: @harism well I dont know for sure if its user access token but when I use the example.php from the sdk I got two arrays - one with the info of my user and one with the info of the application using my account and it has the following items > access_token, base_domain, expires, secret, sesseion_key, sig and uid.

Comment: Ok. So what you're after is an access_token which didn't expire but gave your application indefinite time to do whatsoever on user account who granted your application offline access?

Comment: @harism I granted the application offline access from the same user I use to post on the wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is App Login section in Authorization paragraph in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ .
Read it. You have to call it if you get invalid access token error in order to refresh the token. However, sometimes the token is invalid due to lack of permissions and not because the token is expired